# Flutter equivalent to React Native onLayout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In React Native I can just add an onLayout prop to any component with a callback, and the callback will be invoked with the position and dimension of the component every time a layout change happens that affects this component.

How can I do the same thing in Flutter?

Some code suggests using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_callback);`, but it is only called the first time and it also doesn't seem to guarantee that I can get the size of the widget using `_key.currentContext.findRenderObject()`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's one which is called `LayoutBuilder`. It is designed to to rebuild a widget tree on change, so you have to separate the widget you want to be adjustable in a separate class and implement the `LayoutBuilder`. More info can be found on the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html).

Comment: That worked. Here is the code:
new LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          _imageWidgetWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
        return Image.file(widget._image, key: widget._keyImage);
      })